# Is it safe to use a glass bodum coffee maker on a heating pad?

Tags: coffee-machines

I have a Bonavita drip coffee maker, very similar to [this one](https://bonavita.life/products/metropolitan-8-cup-one-touch-coffee-brewer) with a glass carafe. I've broken the carafe and for reasons, am having problems getting a replacement.

Currently, I'm using a Chemex 8 cup, glass, pour over maker/carafe with the unit and it works just ok. The base is too large, so it doesn't actually sit on the heating pad.

I've found a Bodum, [8 cup glass coffee maker](https://www.bodum.com/us/en/11571-109-pour-over) which fits the unit perfectly. However, the literature says "Not for stove top use". I'm trying to figure out if it's safe to use this maker, as the carafe in my unit as it'll fit and sit directly on the unit's heating pad. The Bodum says it is "borosilicate glass", and Bodum customer service only tells me "this configuration has not been tested". So before I commit to the Bodum, does anyone have practical experience with using this on top of a heating pad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably safe.  I can give you a theoretical answer.  Someone who has repeatedly done it could add anecdotal evidence that theirs hasn't broken yet (or refute the idea if they tried it and it broke).  Explanation:

The question focuses on the glass, so I'll start with that.  Borosilicate glass has a very low coeficient of thermal expansion, making it very tolerant of high temperatures, rapid changes in temperature, and temperature differences within an item.  All borosilicate glass generally has that characteristic, but the exact composition and manufacturing process varies, and not all borosilicate glass is the same.  Some products could handle more extreme situations than others.  But it's likely that any borosilicate glass from a reputable manufacturer could handle the temperatures and conditions encountered in food and beverage preparation.

For some context, the original Pyrex formulation was a type of borosilicate glass patented by Corning.  It could be heated on the stove top or a hot plate, or go from refrigerator to oven without breaking.  Some Pyrex products are still made with borosilicate glass, but the kitchenware now generally is not.  It was changed to tempered soda-lime glass because that's much cheaper to make, and that is usually adequate for most household food and beverage preparation requirements.

The tempered soda-lime glass will handle oven temperatures, but not large, rapid temperature changes or differences within an item.  For example, it can't be used on a stove top or have direct contact with the heating element.  Laboratories that use glassware that will be heated generally stick with borosilicate glass because it is more tolerant of temperature-related issues than tempered soda-lime glass.

A disreputable manufacturer could make crappy borosilicate glass, which didn't have the thermal stability you would expect.  Bodum is a reputable brand, and likely would not use substandard glass.  This item was designed for a different usage.  It sounds like the company has not specifically tested it on a hot plate, so they don't want to speculate.

But all that said, I suspect the issue with the stove-top use warning is not the glass, but the collar, which looks like it's made of cork and leather (and the plastic filter above that).  Those could be susceptible to damage from an open flame on a gas stove, or intense heat from an over-sized electric burner.  But if the bottom of the carafe is properly sized and on a drip coffee maker heating pad, that issue wouldn't be relevant.  It ought to be fine.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful answer. It echoes a bunch of random readings I came across in regard to borosilicate in general. Your thoughts about the other non-glass parts make sense. I feel like the "not for stove top use" is an easy, blanket statement to protect against someone bringing the glass down hard on an unforgiving hot surface and a lawsuit develops because someone tries to grab hot glass.... Just because I have a temp sensor, I shot the heating pad -- its roughly 350F. I was blown away it registered that hot

Answer (score 0):

Years ago, I broke my Bodum but replaced it with a laboratory grade beaker of exactly the same dimensions. The beaker is made of Corning Pyrex brand borosilicate glass and is twice the thickness  of the factory original. It is made to go directly on a gas flame.

The lab beaker was also half the price of a Bodum replacement. It can be difficult to learn the exact diameter when you are internet shopping. That’s the only dimension that is critical.

So, if you get the Bodum, use it as you like. If it can’t take the heat, replace with a lab beaker.